# Lazily instantiate relationships in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, lazy-loading

I have a managed object with robust relationship attributes, meaning the relationships are to objects that are essentially attributes but with descriptive attributes themselves like 'type.' I'd like to lazily instantiate the relationships so I can fill in the descriptive attributes without having to make sure the data I'm getting from the server has that stuff filled in. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Please provide more details. What server? Maybe provide an example...

Answer (score 0):

Core Data lazily loads relationships through a mechanism they refer to as "faulting". This is implemented in the SQLite store type. You can implement it in your own custom NSPersistentStore.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Implementing/Implementing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010706-CH2-SW2